# Lyx Insert graphics dialog closes when selecting an image

Tags: graphics, lyx

I've had no problems with inserting images in Lyx until I updated to MacOS Ventura yesterday. Typically, to insert an image I would insert a float:figure with a frameless box inside of it, then insert graphic.
Until yesterday, after browsing for a graphic and clicking 'open', the entire 'Lyx: Graphics' dialogue would disappear as if nothing happened. I've tried reconfiguring, uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: Unfortunately we have heard a few issues regarding compatibility with Ventura. I can't reproduce the issues (I don't have macOS) unfortunately, and I'm not sure how to fix them. Here is another report of ventura issues: https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg114125.html. The following does not mention ventura but has a similar bug with the graphics dialog: https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/12576

Comment: I also made the mistake of updating to Ventura.
Now it seems that imagemagick is not there anymore. The terminal command `find ./ -name imagemagick` comes back empty. Re-installing MacTeX does not change this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is an issue when one clicks "Browse.." and "Open" a particular figure file to insert into the lyx file. Nothing will appear.

But if you just type the file name into the box to the left of "Browse..", the figure file will in fact appear. For the moment, that is my workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, and what fixed it for me was installing system Python, using the following at the command line

```
xcode-select --install
```

Thanks to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/IvanWerning/status/1599544006962139136?s=20&t=YwmhvMkzrgPRQeB1d-6RaA), pointed out by user @scottkosty in his comment on a (potentially duplicate) [related post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672419/mac-ventura-lyx-graphics?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @TCV Adrian: I did install python3 but still no success. It does not work ...

Comment: @TugrulTemel Try Python 2.7.18 instead. Both versions will live happily next to each other.

Comment: @Peter Camp: Still no success after installing python 2.7.18. I have now two versions of python in my computer. How does an operation picks the right version? I am confused with this installation because my computer is still showing python3 home-brew. When I type in Terminal `python` I get `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3` not the version I just installed.

Comment: @Peter Camp: When I type `python3` in Terminal, I get `tugrultemel@Tugruls-Mac-Studio ~ % python3
Python 3.11.1 (v3.11.1:a7a450f84a, Dec  6 2022, 15:24:06) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.` How can I check if I have the new version placed in the right folder?

Comment: @Peter Camp: I got it by typing `python2.7`. So I have two version in different folders. Still no success...

Comment: @TugrulTemel Did you reconfigure LyX? If you never give it a chance to see what is installed, don't blame me. BTW, if you type @ and then the first letters of the name of the person you want to respond to, you get no chance to mangle their name.

Comment: @Peter Kampf: Thanks for your help. Sorry the name was automatically changed somehow, although I typed your name correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help with fixing the LyX bug, but I can say that including source code and including the graphics manually worked wonders. Seems to be a particular issue with the UI/imagemagick. So just open a code box with Ctrl+L and do the old-fashioned \includegraphics[]{...}

Sadly, the solution above did not work for me (strangely I guess, since I have Python installed through the Conda distribution), but the old-fashioned way did!