# Mac ventura Lyx Graphics

Tags: lyx, mac

I have just updated to MAc ventura and I can no longer install graphics- would really appreciate some help- its critical for lecture notes- thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/663173/lyx-insert-graphics-dialog-closes-when-selecting-an-image (might be a duplicate)

Comment: You could try the suggestion in the following tweet. It has worked for a few people. That said, I don't know anything about macOS. https://twitter.com/IvanWerning/status/1599544006962139136

Comment: Thank you, @scottkosty that worked for me!!

Answer (score 3):

From `https://wiki.lyx.org/Mac/Mac`:

> LyX depends on a usable Python installation on your system. Until macOS 12.3 (Monterey) Apple shipped the OS with Python 2.7. With macOS 12.3 Python isn't part of the OS anymore. It's part of the tools for developers. So it needs to be installed manually to use LyX. This is true for latest macOS (Ventura) too.
>
> [snip]
>
> …  The symptoms for the missing Python 2.7 utility are failures on image conversion …

What is being shipped with MacOS is Python 3.9. The newest version is Python 3.11.1, by the way. But you can still download the most recent Python 2 which is [version 2.7.18](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/) from April 20, 2020. Give it a try, and do not forget to reconfigure LyX after the installation!

That said, I sometimes still see funny behavior regarding graphics files. Sometimes it helps to enter a relative path name instead of the absolute one, and sometimes it helps to change the name of the file. It seems changing the name itself is important, not to what it is changed.

EDIT: The filename funniness is probably caused by me switching to a case-sensitive file system when downgrading to Ventura. Yes, I know, it is a version number up, but it feels like a downgrade.

Comment: Camp:  In Terminal, I tried the following commands to check which version(s) of Python are installed in my Mac OS Ventura. All of the versions below appear installed in my computer. My question is how to activate/use the the version of Python of my choice. For example, if I want to activate Python 2.7.18 when using LyX, what should I do?

Comment: Kampf: Terminal confirms the following versions are  installed in my Mac OS Ventura. Typing in Terminal `% python` gives `Python 3.9.6 (default, Oct 18 2022)` and opens `>>>`. `% python3` gives `Python 3.11.1 (v3.11.1:a7a450f84a, Dec 6 2022)`, `% python3.11` gives `Python 3.11.1 (v3.11.1:a7a450f84a, Dec 6 2022)`, `% python2` gives `Python 2.7.18 (v2.7.18:8d21aa21f2, Apr 19 2020) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0]`, `% python2.7` gives `the same as above`. How can I activate `Python 2.7.18`?

Comment: Kampf: Sorry your name is changed by the system automatically. Apologies for that.

Comment: @TugrulTemel You are so lucky that you have no Umlauts in your name. As I understand it, all versions are active. With "which python" in the terminal you can check which is the default. In my case this is already /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python. To set a specific type the default, please consult [this page](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac)

Comment: In fact, I have a `soft g` in my original name but I use a normal `g` without an accent due to the reason you indicated. Apologies for misspelling of your name due entirely to the machine related reasons. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this as well. What I do not like with the bare LaTeX solution is the appearance of labels as "Broken", so, in place of messing with python, I just opened an old LyX file, copied one graphics from there (the float element as a whole) and paste it into my new file where LyX does not want to import the graphics. Then click on it and rename the included graphics to the one you need. no compilation errors.
best
yehuda